# Highcharts Hide tooltip on mouseOver

Tags: javascript, highcharts

Hi I have added some functionality to my chart which clones the tooltip when the point is clicked and leaves it displayed on the screen until the point is clicked again which turns it off.

Now what I am trying to do is when I mouse over a point which has already been clicked I don't want another tooltip to been shown from the hover. Basically it creates a duplicate and instead I don't want it to show another tooltip when there is already a cloned one there.

Here is the code for the chart that I have created:

```
/***************************************************************
 * start of chart_1_1
 ***************************************************************/
chart_1_1_cloneToolTip = null;
chart_1_1_checkx = [];
chart_1_1_cloneFrame = [];
chart_1_1_cloneText = [];
var chart_1_1_Options = {
    chart: {
        type: 'area'
    },
    xAxis: {
        type: 'datetime'
    },
    yAxis: [{
        reversedStacks: false,
    }, {
        opposite: true,
        min:      0,
        labels: {
            formatter: function() {
                return moment.duration(this.value, 'minutes').format('H [h] m [m]');
            }
        }
    }],
    tooltip: {
        shared:    true,
        useHTML:   true,
        formatter: function () {
            var tooltipcontent = '<div id="tooltip_' + this.x + '"><b>' + moment(this.x).format("dddd, D MMMM YYYY") + '</b>';
            var tooltipfooter = '';
            var mySum          = 0;
            tooltipcontent    += '<table style="width: 100%;">';

            var sortedPoints = this.points.sort(function(a, b){
                return ((b.y < a.y) ? -1 : ((b.y > a.y) ? 1 : 0));
            });

            /**
             * we have to loop here as we don't yet know how many series we will have
             */
            $.each(this.points, function () {
                var symbol     = '■';
                var avg_suffix = '';
                if (this.series.name == 'average dwelltime') {
                    tooltipfooter += '<tr><td><br><span style="color:' + this.point.color + '">' + symbol + '</span> '
                                      + this.series.name + ':</td><td style="text-align: right;"><br>' + moment.duration(this.y, 'minutes').format('H [h] m [m]') + '</td></tr>';
                } else {
                    tooltipcontent += '<tr><td><span style="color:' + this.point.color + '">' + symbol + '</span> '
                                      + this.series.name + ':</td><td style="text-align: right;">' + this.y.toLocaleString() + '</td></tr>';
                    mySum += this.y;
                }

            });

            tooltipcontent += '<tr><td><b>Total:</b></td><td style="text-align: right;"><b>' + mySum.toLocaleString() + '</b><td></tr>';
            tooltipcontent += tooltipfooter;
            tooltipcontent += '</table></div>';
            return tooltipcontent;
        }
    },
    plotOptions: {
        line: {
            pointPlacement: 'between'
        },
        area: {
            stacking:  'normal',
            lineWidth: 1,
            marker: {
                lineWidth: 1
            }
        },
        column: {
            borderWidth: 0,
            stacking:    'normal'
        },
        series: {
            cursor: 'pointer',
            marker: {
                enabled: null,
                symbol:  'circle',
                radius:  2,
                states: {
                    hover: {
                        enabled: true
                    }
                }
            },
            point: {
                events: {
                    mouseOver: function (event) {
                        console.log(event.target.category);
                        if (jQuery.inArray(event.target.category, chart_1_1_checkx) != -1) {

                        }
                    },
                    click: function (event) {
                        //check if point was already clicked
                        var x = chart_1_1_checkx.indexOf(event.point.x);
                        if ( x >= 0 ) {
                            //remove tooltip
                            $(chart_1_1_cloneFrame[x]).remove();
                            $(chart_1_1_cloneText[x]).remove();

                            //remove x coordinate and clone from array --> tooltip can be displayed again
                            chart_1_1_cloneText.splice(x, 1);
                            chart_1_1_cloneFrame.splice(x, 1);
                            chart_1_1_checkx.splice(x, 1);
                        } else {
                            var chart_1_1_cloneDiv = this.series.chart.tooltip.label.div.cloneNode(true),
                            chart_1_1_cloneToolTip = this.series.chart.tooltip.label.element.cloneNode(true);
                            chart_1_1.container.appendChild(chart_1_1_cloneDiv); 
                            chart_1_1.container.firstChild.appendChild(chart_1_1_cloneToolTip);
                            //save coordinates and tooltip object
                            chart_1_1_checkx.push(event.point.x);
                            chart_1_1_cloneFrame.push(chart_1_1_cloneToolTip);
                            chart_1_1_cloneText.push(chart_1_1_cloneDiv);
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    },
    legend: {
        enabled: true
    }
};

chart_1_1_Options.chart.renderTo  = 'chart_1_1';
chart_1_1_Options.xAxis.plotBands = weekends;
chart_1_1_Options.chart.zoomType  = 'x';

/**
 * initialize the chart
 */
var chart_1_1 = new Highcharts.Chart(chart_1_1_Options);
chart_1_1.showLoading();
```

This is the code which I am currently focusing on:

```
point: {
    events: {
        mouseOver: function (event) {
            console.log(event.target.category);
            if (jQuery.inArray(event.target.category, chart_1_1_checkx) != -1) {

            }
        },
        click: function (event) {
            //check if point was already clicked
            var x = chart_1_1_checkx.indexOf(event.point.x);
            if ( x >= 0 ) {
                //remove tooltip
                $(chart_1_1_cloneFrame[x]).remove();
                $(chart_1_1_cloneText[x]).remove();

                //remove x coordinate and clone from array --> tooltip can be displayed again
                chart_1_1_cloneText.splice(x, 1);
                chart_1_1_cloneFrame.splice(x, 1);
                chart_1_1_checkx.splice(x, 1);
            } else {
                var chart_1_1_cloneDiv = this.series.chart.tooltip.label.div.cloneNode(true),
                chart_1_1_cloneToolTip = this.series.chart.tooltip.label.element.cloneNode(true);
                chart_1_1.container.appendChild(chart_1_1_cloneDiv); 
                chart_1_1.container.firstChild.appendChild(chart_1_1_cloneToolTip);
                //save coordinates and tooltip object
                chart_1_1_checkx.push(event.point.x);
                chart_1_1_cloneFrame.push(chart_1_1_cloneToolTip);
                chart_1_1_cloneText.push(chart_1_1_cloneDiv);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

As you can see I am cloning the tooltip on click and I also have another event for `mouseOver` where I am trying to hide the hover tooltip if there is already a duplicate.

The following code is working, this is checking if there is a clone and this part is working correctly. All I need to do now is hide the tooltip

```
if (jQuery.inArray(event.target.category, chart_1_1_checkx) != -1) {}
```

All I need is a line of code in the if statement I specified in my question which hides the tooltip when I hover over it. The if statement is basically saying "There is already a cloned tooltip here so don't bother showing another one when I hover over it"

I have tried the following and none of it works:

```
this.series.chart.tooltip.hide()
$(this.series.chart.tooltip).hide()
this.series.chart.tooltip.div.hide()
```

and much more, if you have any ideas please share. I would imagine its going to be a pretty simple one liner but I just can't figure it out. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Could you reproduce it in an online code editor (jsfiddle, codesandbox)?

Comment: I took someone elses jsfiddle and edited it by adding the clone functionality. All I need is some code adding in the if statement to hide the tooltip. http://jsfiddle.net/vp2x0sda/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can simply achieve it by hiding `this.series.chart.tooltip.label` on `mouseOver` and show it on `mouseOut`.

**Code:**

```
point: {
  events: {
    mouseOver: function(event) {
      if (jQuery.inArray(event.target.category, chart_1_1_checkx) !== -1) {
        this.series.chart.tooltip.label.hide();
      }
    },
    mouseOut: function(event) {
      if (jQuery.inArray(event.target.category, chart_1_1_checkx) === -1) {
        this.series.chart.tooltip.label.show();
      }
    }
  }
}
```

**Demo:**

- http://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/qbh6fp1w

Comment: Thanks for looking into this. I don't think i explained myself correctly because I think you may have misinterpreted my question. I would like to keep the exact same functionality I already have. So when you hover over a point the tooltip is displayed and when you click multiple points multiple tooltips are cloned. The only thing I need doing is when I hover over a point which already has a cloned tooltip I want to hide the HOVER tooltip. The reason for this is because the cloned tooltip is already shown so there is no need to show another one when I hover over that point again.

Comment: So all I need is a line of code in the if statement I specified in my question which hides the tooltip when I hover over it. The if statement is basically saying "There is already a cloned tooltip here so don't bother showing another one when I hover over it"

Comment: Thats perfect thank you, would you like to change your answer and I will make it as correct?